# File Sharing Read & Write issue

Tags: sharing, file

I just ran into this odd behavior today while transferring files via the file sharing feature in Mac OS X.

What happened was most of the files I transferred changed the Read & Write permissions to Read only. These were mainly .css and .html files.

Any one had this before or know whats going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the receiving site did that ? Do you have admin access to it ?

Comment: Which file sharing protocol are you using, AFP or SMB/CIFS? Did you have to type a password to transfer the files? Is your Mac on the sending or receiving end? Which OS is running the other computer?